# Error in getting value from session in JQuery

Tags: jquery, session

I am using the [JQuery-Session-Plugin library](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) for storing data in the session using jQuery. This is working fine for me.

The problem I have is when I try to get the payment amount, I get the output as `[object Object]` instead of an amount, i.e `100`, `70` etc.

Here is my code for paying amount session:

```js
var amount_to_pay = $('#amount_to_pay').html(final_price); 
$.session.set('amount_to_pay', amount_to_pay);
var session_amount_to_pay = $.session.get('amount_to_pay');
console.log(session_amount_to_pay+" is the amount for " + id);
```

Other session values are retrieving fine, Kindly resolve this problem. Sorry if I didn't ask question well, its my first time I am posting my problem here.

Comment: Change your console.log to `console.log(session_amount_to_pay," is the amount for ",id);` to see what your *actual* values are.   One of them is an `object` so when you concat (`+`) with a string you always get `[Object object]`

Comment: Note your code is incomplete:  `var amount_to_pay =` then `$.session.set ... str_amount_to_pay` which you haven't set (in the code provided)

Comment: `var amount_to_pay = $('#amount_to_pay').html(final_price);` also looks strange. You set the HTML content to final_price but seem to want to store the HTML in amount_to_pay. Why not just store final_price?

Comment: *it's my first time I am posting my problem here* - your question is fine - good intro, bit of code, link to the plugin in question.  Just looks like you've used the wrong variable name, unless you can [edit] the question to show the missing variable.

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry, I wrote the code bit wrong here, I updated it in my question. and yes value in `session_amount_to_pay` is object. How can I call Object value through the session?

Comment: @mplungjan still same error.

Comment: It's not about storing/retrieving the object, that's working fine - it's about how you're **looking at it** - using string concat coerces it to `"[Object object]"`

Comment: @freedomn-m error has been removed from the console, I want to use this session value in the form which is on another page, how can display `session_amount_to_pay` there?

Comment: Why not `$.session.set('amount_to_pay', final_price);` and the reason you see object in the console has already been explained

Comment: @mplungjan `$.session.set('amount_to_pay', final_price);` i tried this code, but when I print the output it shows `[object Object]`, and also I don't know why final_price is storing the value as class, this is how I am storing value `final_price = $('#final_price').html(parseInt(calc));`

Comment: Freedomn-m  already explained you why

Comment: @freedomn-m @mplungjan thanks for giving me your precious opinions. It was helpful. `final_price = $('#final_price').html(parseInt(calc));` this statement was storing the complete `span` element, so I stored only `parseInt(calc)` and it worked.